# Python socket client: send data and receive result

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, telnet, python-sockets

I am trying to develop an application in python that has the following behavior. Knowing the existence of an **external socket server**, I can currently connect via telnet and have the following result:

```
telnet localhost 1234
```

When I connect to the server, a message is returned to me, ex:

> welcome

Already connected I can **send some commands** and for each command I have a response:

```
current-time
```

When I send the command *current-time* the server returns:

> 2021-03-29 11:38:55

And the cycle continues... Knowing that everything is working as it should on the server, let's go to the python application. Below is the code of my attempt and I would like to know where I am going wrong since I cannot replicate the mentioned operation (via telnet).

```
1.  client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
2.
3.  client.connect(("localhost", 1234))
4. 
5.  welcome_response = client.recv(4096)
6.  print(welcome_response)
7.
8.  client.send('current-time'.encode())
9.
10. command_response = client.recv(4096)
11. print(command_response)
```

Comments:

1. The *welcome* message is printed (line 6) as result of the first recv call (line 5);
2. The application is stuck on line 10 waiting for the server's response...

Comment: is the server working in Python? can you share it so that we can reproduce?

Comment: No, it's not. And I don't have access to the code, just the documentation (commands and responses)...

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**. The problem was the server was expecting a **breakline** (\n) to identify a client message...